# Inheritance for 2 shared class via interface in Java?

Tags: java, spring-boot, inheritance, design-patterns, polymorphism

In our Java (Spring Boot) app, we have a base request class as shown below:

```
@Data
public class BaseRequest {
    @NotNull
    private UUID uuid;
}
```

There are 2 request extending from this base class for Create and Update as shown below:

```
@Data
public class CreateRequest extends BaseRequest {

    @NotEmpty
    private String apiKey;

    @NotEmpty
    private String locationId;    
}
```

```
@Data
public class UpdateRequest extends BaseRequest {

    private String apiKey;

    private String locationId;    
}
```

The only difference between these 2 classes are mandatory fields (it is required in `CreateRequest`, but not mandatory in `UpdateRequest`.

Here is the method that uses these 2 requests:

```
private void setRequest(SaveRequest request) {
    IntegrationRequest integrationRequest = new IntegrationRequest();
    integrationRequest.setApiKey(request.getApiKey());
    integrationRequest.setLocationId(request.getLocationId());

    // code omitted
}
```

As the fields are not same (required / non required), I have to overload this method. But I tried to use a single `setRequest` method by passing another base class extending the current one and inheriting these 2 requests, but it does not work due to the some unshared fields. I also think to use interface, but I am really confused which approach I should use to solve this problem.

```
private void setRequest(UpdateRequest request) {
    IntegrationRequest integrationRequest = new IntegrationRequest();
    integrationRequest.setApiKey(request.getApiKey());
    integrationRequest.setLocationId(request.getLocationId());

    // code omitted
}
```

So, any idea to use just a single `setRequest` method by passing a shared or base class/interface?

Comment: What java version you are using? With java 16 pattern matching instanceof might be helpful, with java 17 you could make it safe against further subclassing...

Comment: I wouldn't introduce a common interface just because I know I'm able to do that. Not everything needs to be inheritable and inherited. Your `setRequest` method borrows only two values, so why requiring it to accept an instance of either type, SaveRequest(CreateRequest?)/UpdateRequest? Simply let it accept a couple of string parameters, `apiKey` and `locationId`, so that your only method `setRequest` (it's private anyway) would only require what it really needs to start work with.

Comment: Also, I wouldn't accept the answer suggesting you to introduce a common super type just to deal with a private method. This would lead to type bloat: semi-controlled chaos where types don't carry semantic reasons, but pollute the types introduced to the app. If you still think that having a common super type is a good idea, consider introducing "mixin" interfaces like `ProvidesApiKey` and `ProvidesLocationId` with corresponding get-methods. Then you could use (abuse?) Java generics intersection mechanism in some cases. Anyway, creating a new type is not always a good design decision.

Comment: @Turo I use Java **11**

Comment: @terrorrussia-keeps-killing Yes, but there are more than 2 values to be set in `setRequest` method (I omitted that code)

Comment: @terrorrussia-keeps-killing Then, what is your suggestion? Should I overload `setRequest` method by passing 2 different request as `SaveRequest` and `UpdateRequest` ? It seems to be redundant and that's why I am looking for a proper solution for Design Patterns. Any idea?

Comment: Choose your way. For a private method I would never care of such an "issue", just because the scope of the method is private and nobody else (from the programmatic/Java perspective) would care what I do in that class. For your current example, a two-parameter method is just fine. If you have more parameters, add them, nobody can see that method from outside anyway. If you have myriads of such parameters, also consider creating a class between the super class and the concrete classes that could have abstract methods for API key and location ID. Anyway, evaluate how far your new type can go.

Comment: Also, note that you don't really need to be blind against holy design patterns. You way can be pragmatic. In my first option I suggested you to destructure the values required to build the integration request from just because the amount of the values is just two, and one wouldn't need to build an intermediate object just to pass two values. This is obviously a not good way for a private method. The generics intersection option with a couple of interfaces is semantically the same (you still can transparently know what the method can accept), but Occam's razor would cut them off.

Comment: George's suggestion seems to work. It seems better to overload method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
public interface Request {
    String getApiKey();
    String getLocationId();
}

@Data
public class CreateRequest extends BaseRequest implements Request {
    @NotEmpty
    private String apiKey;
    @NotEmpty
    private String locationId;
}

@Data
public class UpdateRequest extends BaseRequest implements Request {
    private String apiKey;
    private String locationId;
}

private void setRequest(Request request) {
    CreateRequest integrationRequest = new CreateRequest();
    integrationRequest.setApiKey(request.getApiKey());
    integrationRequest.setLocationId(request.getLocationId());

    // code omitted
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. But I should not change `BaseRequest` and I am not sure if the 2 fields (apiKey and locationId) is both required and non-required for create and update. Any idea?

Comment: Answer updated with an interface without modifying BaseRequest.